# How do i validate a Json file using Json schema in Mongo?

Tags: json, mongodb, jsonschema

I have a JSON file and i want to validate the file using JSON Schema on MongoDB.
How do i import the JSON Schema to MongoDB and then validate the JSON File.
JSON file is already in one collection so i want to validate without importing a new JSON file.

JSON:

```
{
"Book": {
    "Year:2016-2017": {
        "Crs": [{
            "Cr": {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5a439ff4fc0900f06fb470a4"
                },
                "Number": 35,
                "Pag": 8,
                "Desc": "Embl",
                "Ad": "S",
                "Type": "Embl"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

}

JSON schema:

```
{
"type": "object",
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
"id": "http://jsonschema.net",
"required": false,
"properties": {"Book": {
    "type": "object",
    "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book",
    "required": false,
    "properties": {"Year:2016-2017": {
        "type": "object",
        "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017",
        "required": false,
        "properties": {"Crs": {
            "type": "array",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs",
            "required": false,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0",
                "required": false,
                "properties": {"Cr": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0/Cr",
                    "required": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "Ad": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0/Cr/Ad",
                            "required": false
                        },
                        "Desc": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0/Cr/Desc",
                            "required": false
                        },
                        "Number": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0/Cr/Number",
                            "required": false
                        },
                        "Pag": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0/Cr/Pag",
                            "required": false
                        },
                        "Type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0/Cr/Type",
                            "required": false
                        },
                        "_id": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0/Cr/_id",
                            "required": false,
                            "properties": {"$oid": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Book/Year:2016-2017/Crs/0/Cr/_id/$oid",
                                "required": false
                            }}
                        }
                    }
                }}
            }
        }}
    }}
}}}
```

I want to validate the JSON using the schema with mongodb.

Comment: Import the json schema when you create collection and it will validate documents as you insert them. Something like `db.createCollection(colname, {
   validator: {$jsonschema: schema }});`

Comment: @Veeram I already have the json file (not the schema) in the collection.There is anyway of validate that file without creating a new collection?Like XML Schema

Comment: So you would like to validate the json file while querying with json schema you have with you ? Can you provide some samples may be ?

Comment: @Veeram yes i would  like to validate while querying.

Comment: @Veeram i add some code to the question.

Comment: May be there is a way but validation as I understand are done on insertions and updates. What is your use case ? Is creating temporary collection with schema and then querying your main collection followed by insertions/updates into temporary collection for validation an option for your use case ?

Comment: @Veeram i want to add a new "Cr" but it needs to respect the JSON Schema.(Insertion/Update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> JSON file is already in one collection so i want to validate without importing a new JSON file.

As of MongoDB v3.6.x, [document schema validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) only occurs during updates and inserts, existing documents do not undergo validation checks until modification. This means that your existing JSON document in a MongoDB collection will not be validated by the validation rule(s) that you just applied.

Note that [$jsonSchema operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#op._S_jsonSchema) and [JSON-SCHEMA](http://json-schema.org/) support is new in MongoDB version 3.6.

> i want to add a new "Cr" but it needs to respect the JSON Schema.(Insertion/Update)

Once you specified a document schema validation on a collection, any update operations will trigger validation checks on the affected documents.

For example, if you have an existing document in a collection as below:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "crs": [
        {
          "cr": {
            "d": 2,
            "e": "two"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you then apply a validator as below:

```
// Validator for nested array of objects.  
var schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "a": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "b": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "crs": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "cr": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "d": {
                                            "bsonType": "int",
                                        },
                                        "e": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                        }
                                    }
                            }}
                        }
                }}
        }}
}}}
db.runCommand({"collMod": "collectionName", 
               "validator": { "$jsonSchema": schema}}
);
```

When you update the existing document to add a new `cr`, the *whole* document will be validated.

```
db.collectionName.update({_id: 1}, {"$push":{
                                       "a.b.crs":{
                                            "cr":{
                                               "d": NumberInt(20),
                                               "e": "new element"}}}
});
```

Any pre-existing documents that are not valid according to your document schema validation rule(s), you will have to correct the documents first before updating them.